# Javascript Lazyload queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery LazyLoad plugin in my project to display large column of small pictures. The plugin helps really much, the only issue is that on page load it makes page/scrolling/.. so slow as it loads all the initial (visible) images (around 60 images  of size 40x40) at once.

It would be amazing if it loaded one after another with a time gap between loads, for example 800ms, because I don't really need them to appear straight away. I believe that would make user experience more comfortable.

Unfortunately I am not too good with Javascript. I tried to use jQuery delay function, but it did not help. I would really appreciate any help.

Related code:

```
    $(self).one("appear", function() {
        if (!this.loaded) {
            $("<img />")
                .bind("load", function() {
                    $(self)
                        .hide()
                        .attr("src", $(self).attr("data-original"))
                        [settings.effect](settings.effectspeed);
                    self.loaded = true;
                })
                .attr("src", $(self).attr("data-original"));
        };
    });
```

Comment: Delay only works for the fx queue

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `data-origional` attribute on the images to their source then you can run somthing like this on `document.ready`:

```
$(function () {
    function load_image($image) {
        if (count >= $images.length) {clearInterval(timer); return false;}
        $image.attr('src', $image.attr('data-origional'));
        count++;
    }
    var $images = $('img'),
        count   = 0,
        timer   = setInterval(function () {
            load_image($images.eq(count));
        }, 800);
});
```